# Inference on a factor graph (Sum-product Algorithm)

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, information-theory, machine-learning, bayesian

I was going through the sum-product algorithm which can be used to find marginal distribution efficiently(and exactly) when the **factor graph is a tree**.

I found it difficult to understand the way they have **expressed the joint probability density function eq 8.62**

[image]

I have gone through many sources and have failed to understand this.Can someone give an example and help me to understand why 8.62 holds? What does X(s) mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption here is that the probability density $p(x)$ can be represented as a product of several factors that each only depend on a subset of the latent variables. To give a very simple example, consider

$p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f_1(x_1, x_2) f_2(x_2, x_3) f_3(x_3)$

with the associated factor graph

```
x_1 --- |f_1| --- x_2 --- |f_2| --- x_3 --- |f_3|.
```

If we now want to find the marginal probability $p(x_2)$, we need to sum (in the case of discrete variables) or integrate (in the case of continuous variables) over all admissible values of the other latent variables:

$p(x_2) = \sum\limits_{x_1,x_3} p(x_1, x_2, x_3)$.

To do so, it is convenient to partition the factor graph into subtrees emerging from the variable node $x_2$. Here, we only have two subtrees; the left one containing only the factor $f_1$ and the right one, containing the factors $f_2$ and $f_3$.
To each subtree, we associate a function $F_s$ that is equal to the product of all factor nodes contained in that subtree, and a set $X_s$ that contains all variable nodes contained in that subtree.

Using these definitions for the present example yields

$p(x_1, x_2, x_3) = f_1(x_1, x_2) f_2(x_2, x_3) f_3(x_3) = \prod\limits_{i=1}^2 F_i(x_2, X_i)$,

with $X_1 = x_1$ and $X_2 = x_3$, and $F_1(x_2, X_1) = f_1(x_1, x_2)$ and $F_2(x_2, X_2) = f_2(x_2, x_3) f_3(x_3)$.

---

Just as a side note, I find the introduction to factor graphs by Hans-Andrea Loeliger very useful and accessible:
https://people.kth.se/~tjtkoski/factorgraphs.pdf